# Filter by date with MySql

Tags: mysql

Here the query I have actually:

```
SELECT month(BIL_Date) AS month,
    sum(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity) AS sumval
    FROM `___BillableDatas`
    WHERE BIL_HotelId = 'AAA00' 
    AND BIL_Date BETWEEN "2017-05-01" AND "2017-05-31"
    AND BIL_Type = "Night" OR BIL_Type = "Item"
    GROUP BY year(BIL_Date), month(BIL_Date);
```

The problem is with the following value, the query returns me some datas for the April month whereas I would like to search from May 1st to 31st.

Where is my mistake please ?

My actual table is:

```
BIL_Date        BIL_Rate        BIL_Quantity        BIL_HotelId
2017-04-14      95.00           1                   AAA00
2017-04-14      16.00           2                   AAA00
2017-04-14      10.00           1                   AAA00
2017-04-15      95.00           1                   AAA00
2017-04-15      16.00           2                   AAA00
2017-04-15      10.00           1                   AAA00
```

Thanks.

Comment: An astute use of parentheses

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry.